# SonarLint for Visual Studio failing with 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

We are trying to use SonarLint on Visual studio 2015 and our Sonarqube version is 4.5.7.

But it is not binding its SophisWebApi to sonar server because of below error :

`Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
SonarQube request failed: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). 
   Cannot download the quality profile for language C#`

I guess this is version incompatibility issue. Can someone pls share which version of SonarLint is compatible with Sonarqube version is 4.5.7. It will be really if version compatibility details are maintained somewhere to avoid confusions (in case of [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) and [SonarLint for IntelliJ](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/) IDEA this information is available in News section where Release history is maintained. Maintaining at least this much even for [SonarLint for Visual Studio](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/) would help)

Comment: SonarQube 4.5.7 is really old, you won't be able to use SonarLint with this verion. 
Latest LTS version is 5.6.6 and next LTS version is planned to be released in a couple of months.
In order to use SonarLint you have to upgrade to latest LTS.

Comment: Thanks Eric, for your quick response. We know that SonarQube 4.5.7 is really old but waiting for 6.x LTS release to simplify our upgrade activity as it is being used by many users.But was there any earlier versions of SonarLint supporting SonarQube 4.5.7 (one LTS version lesser than current LTS)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. SonarQube 4.5.x series does not contains the API required to use SonarLint.

Comment: @EricHartmann the content of you comments would make a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding my answer in instead of a comment :

SonarQube 4.5.x does not contains the API required to use SonarLint. You should use SonarQube 5.6.x (last LTS version) or the next one 6.7 that will be released in a couple of months.